# A doubt on the expression "real-valued" in 3.8 (c) of Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces

I investigated the proof closely, but found no role played by the expression "real-valued". Thus, my thought is that it can be replaced by "complex-valued" for a simple and trivial generalization.

(In the last sentence, (a) is the proposition that a topology of a compact Hausdorff space cannot be weakened without losing the Hausdorff separation axiom and cannot be strengthened without losing compactness.)
[image]

Comment: Yes you can, but you gain nothing extra since then you may replace $|f_n(p)-f_n(q)|$ with $|\operatorname{Re}(f_n)(p)-\operatorname{Re}(f_n)(q)|$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, my posting is especially for things like your comment. Since $(f_n)$ is a separating family of complex-valued functions on X, your replacement may spoil the separating property of the family, so that $d$ may fail to be a metric. Thus, only the expression "real-valued" can be changed with no other single part in the proof being changed.

Comment: correct! I meant to write $|\operatorname{Re}(f_n)(p)-\operatorname{Re}(f_n)(q)|+|\operatorname{Im}(f_n)(p)-\operatorname{Im}(f_n)(q)|$, which yields the sum of two pseudo-metrics adding up to a metric. The point is that you might as well assume that $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ separates points and take values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or in a Banach space. All that is fine but it is just splitting hairs.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, you are right, but I think one need not make such a change of the definition of the metric in the proof, because the current definition of the metric causes no problem. Just change of real valued to complex valued is moderate and enough for the use in the later part of the book, the detail of which I will omit. Thank you

Comment: It all depends what application you have in front of you. In Rudin's functional analysis book, it is enough to consider real valued $f_n$ that separate points. If you happen to have $E$-valued ($E$ a Banach space) functions that separate points, you can also construct a metric on the underlying space $X$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, Yeah. My feeling is that I'd employ the intuition you mentioned in a different context before long. Thank you.